# DataStax Studio throws "class is not registered" when querying vertices of type com.datastax.driver.dse.geometry.point

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-studio

I'm using  DataStax Studio gremlin editor in production mode (using clusters)

each time I query vertexes with Point property type ,the studio throws exception : 
"class is not registered".. com.datastax.driver.dse.geometry.point

Please help.

Comment: Please show your exact code (schema definition, data insertion, and queries).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using DataStax Studio 1.0.1 with code: `schema.config().option('graph.schema_mode').set('Development'); graph.addVertex('point',Geo.point(1,2))`. Can you provide version info and a code snippet? Also, how did you install DSE? Are you using LCM?

Comment: I copied the entire exception:

Comment: Note: toRegister this class use kryo.register(com.datastax.driver.dse.geomerty.point.class) serialization Trace: value (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertexProperty) properties (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex) .          I installed dse latest version  using LCM , and I installed the latest dse studio also. all the quries fails for all vertexes which has property Type Point

Comment: I use schema.config().option('graph.schema_mode').set('Production​');

Comment: I load data using graphLoader

Comment: can please show me an example of a vertex which has property type point shema and load data using graphLoader .

Comment: maybe the problem is because the graph and the schema created in studio for production mode instead of gremlin-console?